Loading image with javascript in a Blazor Hybrid app
I'm working on a Blazor Hybrid app which uses ChartJS to display data.
The chart has a background image which can be changed by selecting a new image with a file picker.
To my understanding javascript can only reach the wwwroot folder.
So I have added an Images folder to the wwwroot folder with the Image.bmp inside.
In the javascript file I have a Load function like below:
async function LoadImg() {
    await new Promise(r => {
        image.onload = r;
        image.src = "Images/Image.bmp";
    });
...}

In the razor file I have a button which triggers following function:
async Task LoadImage()
{
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("LoadImg");
}

The idea I had was to copy with File.Copy the new image with the same name Image.bmp in the wwwroot/Images folder and launch the LoadImg again.
PickOptions options = new()
    {
        PickerTitle = "Select image file",
        FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Images
    };

try
{
    FileResult result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
    if (result != null)
    {
        try{
            File.Copy(result.FullPath, 
                "C:\\Visual Studio Projects\\IRIS-LOC-0.2\\IRIS-LOC\\IRIS-LOC\\wwwroot\\Images\\Image.bmp", 
                true);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error.Message}");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error picking file: {ex.Message}");
}

This is unfortunately not working.
The file is copied to the wwwroot/Images folder, but the LoadImg function is not loading the new image.
Wenn I restart the app, the new image is loaded.
So why is the LoadImg function only working the first time?
